# Fetch result before submission

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I work in my company creating an internal php/html/javascript framework where there is a form with datas to be injected into a database.
In this framework I have implemented the use of "javascript modules" to do some checks in the webpage.
I've been requested that one of these modules stop completely the submission of the form if it does not respect some specifics requirements.

I've been able to do what I want using XMLHttpRequest with async=false but this is deprecated.

I've been trying to use 'fetch' with 'await' but i'm still not able to retrieve fetch result before submission.

I do not want to do the submission from the fetch result because there are many other modules which actions that have to be done before submitting the form.

My problem is that fetch result is still working in async mode and send me that result after the form submission.

I read that using fetch in a function could help but I was not able to get the expected behaviour.

Could you please help me ?

I've recreated a sample that you can find bellow...

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myButton" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    <div>
        <textarea rows="5" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // Global Vars
    let i = 0;
    let doSubmit = true
    let events = []

    // Send to <code>
    let logCode = (txt=false) => {
        let e = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
        e.value = txt ? `${e.value}${txt}\n` : `[${i++}]\n`;
    };

    // Begin check before submit form
    events.push(function(){
        doSubmit.length = 0 // Flush Array
        logCode();  // Erase datas from textarea
        logCode('Do fetch checking...');
    });

    // Get Fetch Result
    events.push(function(){
        const fetchDatas = async function(){
            const response = await fetch('response.txt');
            const json = await response.json();
            return json.allow;
        }
        fetchDatas()
            .then(allow => doSubmit = allow);
    });

    // Submit form
    events.push(function(){
        logCode(`fetch Allow: ${doSubmit}`);
        if (doSubmit){
            logCode(`Allow submit form !`);
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
        for (let i=0; i<events.length; i++){
            events[i]();
        }
    })
});
```

response.txt

```
{
    "allow": false
}
```

Comment: Your approach is completly wrong. You add many event handlers to the click of the button and expect that they are called in the order you added them. You can never bet on that. Add only one event handler and write your code in this handlers function as it should be executed

Comment: Beside my approch, even executed in the specific order that I need I still have this problem`, i'll modify it so you can test !

Comment: Why use that `events` array of functions? Simply write one single `async` function that executes the code in the sequence that you want, and can `await` the fetch request like you already do.

Comment: You are starting one event after another without checking any result or completing of the vent before. How should that work? 
As Bergi said: Get rid of this event array and write normal code.

Comment: Guys, this is not the final code, this is just to reproduce the problem that I'm facing, is that the async fetch mode give me the result too late.
Just imagine that you have a page with a form, you want to have dynamic modules that can be inserted in any moment of the framework life...

Comment: Still, if the "dynamic modules" are (or: can be) asynchronous, make them promise-returning (`async`) function and `await` the `events[i]()` calls in the loop